# For loop not being itereated properly with promises

Tags: node.js, typescript, promise, scripting

I've being converting a project from Javascript to Typescript and encountered some problems when running a retry on fail system. This system works fine on vanilla JS but it seems to fail somewhere on Typescript.

```js
    var t: number = 500;
    var max: number = 5;

    const rejectDelay = (reason: string): Promise<any> => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            log.warn('Unable to connect to database. Trying again...');
            setTimeout(() => reject.bind(null, reason), t);
        });
    };

    const dbConn = async (): Promise<void> => {
        let conn = await db.pool
            .getConnection()

            .then((message: any) => {
                if (!message.isValid()) {
                    throw message.isValid;
                } else {
                    return message.isValid;
                }
            });
    };

    const connected = (res: string): void => {
        log.info('Connection to database is successful.');
        log.info(`App is running in port ${envs.port} in ${envs.mode} mode.`);
    };

    const notConnected = async (err: any): Promise<void> => {
        log.error('Max attempts exceeded, app will exit...');
        process.exit(1);
    };

    var p: Promise<any> = Promise.resolve();

    for (var i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        console.log(i);
        p = p.catch(dbConn).catch(rejectDelay);
    }

    p = p.then(connected).catch(notConnected);
```

after running the project this is  expected result:

```
[info] 2022-05-18 01:13:03: Router users registered...
[info] 2022-05-18 01:13:03: Router utils registered...
0
[warn] 2022-05-18 01:12:59: Unable to connect to database. Trying again...
1
[warn] 2022-05-18 01:12:59: Unable to connect to database. Trying again
2
[warn] 2022-05-18 01:12:59: Unable to connect to database. Trying again
3
[warn] 2022-05-18 01:12:59: Unable to connect to database. Trying again
4
[error] 2022-05-18 01:13:44: Max attempts exceeded, app will exit...
```

and this is what I get:

```
[info] 2022-05-18 01:13:03: Router users registered...
[info] 2022-05-18 01:13:03: Router utils registered...
0
1
2
3
4
[error] 2022-05-18 01:13:44: Max attempts exceeded, app will exit...
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `() => reject.bind(null, reason)` is surely not what you want.

Comment: Please post the working javascript as well. Also, does your typescript transpile to the same code as the original javascript when you build it?

Comment: `p = p.then(dbConn)` in the loop looks wrong. Even if you don't get errors, it will open `max` connections?!

Comment: fixed the `p.then()` to `p.catch()`as it's supposed to be.

Comment: Ah, that `catch` chain makes more sense, but what do you want `.catch(rejectDelay);` to do? Did you mean `p = p.catch(rejectDelay).catch(dbConn);`? Or `p = p.catch(()=>fulfillDelay().then(dbConn));`? Also the `catch` chain would need to start with either `Promise.reject()` or `dbCon()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to stop on the first connection and you want it to wait a timeout before trying again upon a connection failure, then you need a different approach.  Here's one way to do it (note you may have to fix up some TypeScript stuff as I'm a plain JS developer, not TypeScript):

```
const t: number = 500;
const max: number = 5;

const rejectDelay = (reason: string): Promise<any> => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        log.warn('Unable to connect to database. Trying again...');
        setTimeout(resolve, t, reason);
    });
};

const dbConn = async (): Promise<void> => {
    const conn = await db.pool.getConnection();
    if (!conn.isValid()) {
        throw message.isValid;
    }
    return conn;
};

const connected = (res: string): void => {
    log.info('Connection to database is successful.');
    log.info(`App is running in port ${envs.port} in ${envs.mode} mode.`);
};

const notConnected = async (err: any): Promise<void> => {
    log.error('Max attempts exceeded, app will exit...');
    process.exit(1);
};

async function getConn() {
    for (let i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        try {
            console.log(i);
            let conn = await dbConn();
            return conn;
        } catch(e) {
            await rejectDelay(e);
        }
    }
    throw new Error("database connection failed, all retries used");
} 

getConn().then(result => {
    connected(result);
}).catch(err => {
    notConnected(err);
});
```

---

To attempt to debug this myself, I added a bunch of debugging and made it so it would run stand-alone in nodejs.  You can copy this to a separate file and run it by itself and see how it works.  I've made `dbConn()` such that it fails the first 3 times, then succeeds the fourth time so you can see how it works:

```
const t = 500;
const max = 5;

function delay(t, v) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, t, v));
}

// simulate db.pool.getConnection()
// fails first 3 times, succeeds after that
const db = {
    pool: {
        async getConnection() {
            await delay(500);
            ++db.pool.cntr;
            if (db.pool.cntr <= 3) {
                throw new Error("Can't connect to Database");
            } else {
                return { connected: true, isValid: () => true };
            }
        },
        cntr: 0
    }
}

// simulate log.info() and log.error
const log = {
    info(...args) {
        console.log(...args);
    },
    error(...args) {
        console.log(...args);
    },
    warn(...args) {
        console.log(...args);
    }
}

// simulate envs
const envs = {
    port: 3000,
    mode: "development"
}

const rejectDelay = (reason) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        log.warn('Unable to connect to database. Trying again...');
        setTimeout(resolve, t, reason);
    });
};

const dbConn = async () => {
    const conn = await db.pool.getConnection();
    if (!conn.isValid()) {
        throw message.isValid;
    }
    return conn;
};

const connected = (res) => {
    log.info('Connection to database is successful.');
    log.info(`App is running in port ${envs.port} in ${envs.mode} mode.`);
};

const notConnected = async (err) => {
    log.error('Max attempts exceeded, app will exit...');
    process.exit(1);
};

async function getConn() {
    for (let i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        try {
            console.log(i);
            let conn = await dbConn();
            console.log(i, "after");
            return conn;
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(i, "catch");
            await rejectDelay(e);
            console.log(i, "after rejectDelay");
        }
    }
    throw new Error("database connection failed, all retries used");
}

getConn().then(result => {
    connected(result);
}).catch(err => {
    notConnected(err);
});
```

Comment: Tried it, same result

Comment: It stops after first iteration of the for cycle

Comment: @andremonteiro1996 - I fixed that by moving the try/catch inside the loop and making the `rejectDelay()` resolve rather than reject.

Comment: still get stuck in the first iteration of the cycle

Comment: @andremonteiro1996 - What do you mean stuck in the first iteration?  What exactly happens?  Do you realize that if it connects, it is supposed to exit the `for` loop when it connects as there's no point in continuing the loop when you already have a connection?   That's what this code is designed to do.  Did you change `rejectDelay()` to resolve if you're testing connection failures?

Comment: yep, i did everything as you instructed. what happens is... i dont know, it can't connect because i have wamp stopped, so I can try this. it prints 0 (iteration) and unable to connect... and nothing else happens

Comment: @andremonteiro1996 - That doesn't give me anything to go on to try to help you further.  I'm stuck unless you can provide a more detailed description of what problem you're running into.

Comment: it tries to connect the first time and then... i dont really know... i have console logs everywhere to try and debug it

Comment: @andremonteiro1996 - I fixed another problem in `rejectDelay()` - see fixed code in my answer.  You were calling `resolve.bind()`, but not actually calling `resolve()`.  I just removed the `.bind()` and arrow function callback entirely and used the extra arguments that `setTimeout()` supports.

Comment: the last modification makes it retry and in the end the app should shutdown, it doesnt.

Comment: @andremonteiro1996 - OK, I've added that feature to the implementation with a `throw` after the `for` loop since the code should only get there if all retries failed.

Comment: that throw works but not as intented, the app's final print should be the one on notConnected

Comment: @andremonteiro1996 - So, what exactly is the problem then?  You have to describe what you're observing and how that is different than what you desire.

Comment: I'm trying man...

Look the app needs to retry connection to database, if connects the whole app starts running, otherwise the app shutdown... unfortunately can't find the source code i based mine on...
TL;DR tries to connect x times if first is not succeeded, after x times shutdown.

Comment: What I'm observing is the app being stuck on the first iteration of the cycle, not continuing, or if I reject the promise, tries one time and shuts down after that first attempt, or even, the cycle run all iterations and only then attempting to connect

Comment: @andremonteiro1996 - I added a testable, runnable, standalone version to the end of my answer.  You can run this in its own file and see how it works.  Not much else I can do here.  Perhaps your use of the database connection is wrong - I don't know.  You don't even say what database API you're using.  But, the logic here in my answer works if you integrate it properly with your database.

Comment: ok, works, but still same problem as before; in the end app doesnt shutdown, but rather says it connected successfully

Comment: @andremonteiro1996 - If you're running my test program, that is designed to simulate success after three retries.  If you change to `if (db.pool.cntr <= 10)` in the test program,  you will see it hit the `notConnected()` function and exit.

Comment: well, if i have the database service running, the app still tries to connect (unsuccessfully) and exits

Comment: @andremonteiro1996 - That is something you're doing wrong in your db connection code.  Nothing I can debug here.  Are you sure about the `if (!conn.isValid())`.  I've never seen that before.  What database driver module are you using?

Comment: I'm using Mariadb as database driver

Comment: @andremonteiro1996 - Just try one line of code to connect to your database all by itself and see if that works.  I don't think your database connection issue has anything to do with what you're asking about in this question - I think it's something else.

Comment: I think you're right.... this has something to do with the async/await...